DataGridRowHeader IsPressed event not changing Background
I have a custom style for a DataGridRowHeader and the Trigger IsPressed doesn't seem to fire. IsMouseOver works fine though. I basically have the same style with its triggers for a DataGridColumnHeader and everything works perfectly.
Why is not working for a RowHeader and is there an alternative?
<Style x:Key="DataGridRowHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                <Grid x:Name="gridRow">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Border}" 
                            BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" 
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="8,10,7,10" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_TopHeaderGripper" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                           Style="{StaticResource RowHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_BottomHeaderGripper" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                           Style="{StaticResource RowHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Highlight}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="Red"/> <!-- This does not work -->
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

This trigger here doesn't fire:
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="Red"/> <!-- This does not work -->
</Trigger>

